# Intersection of dense set and subset?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am currently reading a book that says: The intersection of a dense set $W \subset X$ and an open set $O \subset X$ is again dense in $O$. Actually, this sounds as if it would matter that $O$ is open? Is it not true that for all $M \subset X$: $W \cap M$ is dense in $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take the complement $M = X \setminus W$.